# Full postback triggered by LinkButton inside UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel, linkbutton

I'm having trouble dynamically adding controls inside an update panel with partial postbacks.I generate some LinkButton dynamically in code behind and set trigger of them, but when I fire them they full postback, even LinkButton Event does not get called when I fire them.They are placed in the 'divPageNumber'

*.aspx:

```
</asp:DataList>
               <table style="width: 100%">
                   <tr style="width: 10%">
                       <td>
                           <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkPrevious" runat="server" Font-Bold="True"
                               NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" OnClick="lnkPrevious_Click" Width="100px">&lt;&lt;صفحه قبل</asp:LinkButton>
                       </td>
                       <td style="width: 80%">
                           <div id="divPageNumber" dir="rtl" runat="server">
                           </div>
                       </td>
                       <td style="width: 10%">
                           <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkNext" runat="server" Font-Bold="True"
                               NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" OnClick="lnkNext_Click" Width="80px">صفحه بعد&gt;&gt;</asp:LinkButton>
                       </td>
                   </tr>
               </table>
           </ContentTemplate>
           <Triggers>
               <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="LinkButton1" EventName="Command"></asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger>
               <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="LinkButton2" EventName="Command" />
               <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="LinkButton3" EventName="Command" />
               <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="LinkButton4" EventName="Command" />
               <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="LinkButton5" EventName="Command" />
               <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="LinkButton6" EventName="Command" />
               <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="LinkButton7" EventName="Command" />
               <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="LinkButton0" EventName="Command" />
               <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSearchHead" EventName="Command" />
               <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="LinkButton8" EventName="Command" />
               <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="lnkNext" EventName="Click" />
               <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="lnkPrevious" EventName="Click" />                   
           </Triggers>

       </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and *.cs:

```
LinkButton btnPage;
            for (int i = 1; i <= objPagedDataSource.PageCount; i++)
            {
                btnPage = new LinkButton();                    
                btnPage.ID = "btnPage" + i.ToString();                    
                if (i == GetCurrentPageNumber + 1)
                    btnPage.Font.Bold = true;
                btnPage.Width = 10;
                btnPage.Style["margin-right"] = "2px";
                btnPage.Style["margin-left"] = "2px";
                btnPage.Text = i.ToString();

                if (brand != "" && brand != null)
                    btnPage.PostBackUrl = "Default.aspx?brand=" + brand + "&Page=" + i.ToString();
                else if (model != "" && model != null)
                    btnPage.PostBackUrl = "Default.aspx?model=" + model + "&Page=" + i.ToString();
                else
                    btnPage.PostBackUrl = "Default.aspx?Page=" + i.ToString();

                divPageNumber.Controls.Add(btnPage);

                LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)divPageNumber.FindControl("btnPage" + i.ToString());
                lb.Click += new EventHandler(lnkdel_OnClick);

                //Creates a new async trigger
                AsyncPostBackTrigger trigger = new AsyncPostBackTrigger();
                trigger.ControlID = lb.UniqueID;
                trigger.EventName = "Click";
                UpdatePanel1.Triggers.Add(trigger);

                ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(lb);
            }
            UpdatePanel1.Update();

protected void lnkdel_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void lnkPrevious_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //GetCurrentPageNumber -= 1;
        //BindDataToRepeter();
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx?Page=" + (Convert.ToInt32(Page.Request["Page"]) - 1).ToString());
    }
    protected void lnkNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //GetCurrentPageNumber += 1;
        //BindDataToRepeter();

        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx?Page=" + (Convert.ToInt32(Page.Request["Page"]) + 1).ToString());
    }
```

'lnkNext' and 'lnkPrevious' is static added and work. but 'lnkdel_OnClick' doesn't work.

What am I doing?

thanks

Comment: As far as full postback is concerned, that's by design. All of the Page’s life cycle events are still executed even during partial postbacks. More info at, http://encosia.com/are-you-making-these-3-common-aspnet-ajax-mistakes/

Comment: I don't understand this article, can you help me and fix my code.

Comment: When you say full postback, do you mean you see the postback happening (page gets re-loaded) or, you do not see postback happening but all of the page life-cycle events are getting fired?

Comment: When I fire 'lnkNext' or 'lnkPrevious' and dynamic buttons Load event occurs, and there is this code in Load event : **if(!Page.IsPostBack){}**, but when I fire dynamic buttons **IsPostBack is true**. but The buttons that are static **IsPostBack is false**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve my problem from this thread

http://forums.asp.net/t/1895457.aspx/1